# Using @IBInspectable setting a Bool failed

Tags: ios

This is my class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBInspectable var double: Double!
    @IBInspectable var string: String!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

And I set `double` and `string` in Storyboard

[image]

I run the app. The `string` can be set correctly but `double` failed.The console output:

```
Failed to set (double) user defined inspected property on (Test1.ViewController): [<Test1.ViewController 0x7f892ad25910> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key double.
```

Could tell me why the setting failed ? Thanks!

Comment: Try making it an NSNumber.